# PBKDF2 (or BCrypt) hash implementation for Apache HTTPD or APR

Tags: security, httpd, hash

Does anyone know of (simple) way to use PBKDF2 or BCrypt as a password hash within Apache HTTPD.

The general scenario is that I have a resource in /private that I would like to restrict to a given group of users. Those users will have passwords stored in a database and verified using a `mod_auth_dbd`.

I would **like** to get away from using SSHA.

I can see in the Apache apr-util that there is a function `apr_password_validate` (which handles all the now frowned upon hash types); and in apr_crypto_openssl.c there is `crypto_passphrase` which is an implementation of PBKDF2.

Has anyone welded the two together?
(or have I just missed something obvious somewhere in the Apache docs?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after further review, it seems that everything was a lot simpler than I'd imagined.

HTTPD uses the system provided crypt function, and so leverages its modularity.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(Unix)#Modular_crypt.283.29_Algorithms

In theory it supports BCrypt directly (although I did not test it).  I did test SHA-512 using the $6 prefix.

So setting a password as calculated below achieves the desired result:

```
salt = 'fGn9LR75';
puts 'quohjo5oor4ac3Deolei'.crypt('$6$' + salt);
=>    
"$6$fGn9LR75$juRSrMtKBa8pdZ8tbTouUvDItoF9Fp.LVk8Kqv2ZL5T.R.q/nUQNGePve1Ge/8rDf/xqUwgpY.3F1MQ0qtauf0"
```

Answer (score 0):

For future searchers, note that bcrypt support was added to Apache in version 2.4.4, released in February 2013.

$ htpasswd -nbB -C 11 username password
username:$2y$11$p1icdLB/EqI2z2EPt6JrQOUdy1GzHg5GdDWcwdj3MIXJLSkgrILoa